# Angular2 submit POST programmatically

Tags: angular

The below is jQuery that submits a form programmatically

```
$('#form').attr('action', window.siteRoot + 'Users/Cards/').submit();
```

How can I do the same with Angular2?

The problem with the below code is that it's Ajax so it wants a return response. I don't want to return as I want to go to a new view.

```
return this.http.post(GlobalVariables.SITE_ROOT + url, dto, { headers })
        .subscribe(function (data) {
        console.log('received response');
    });
```

Thanks much

Comment: Just use a form instead?.. if you don't need to perform asyncronous requests, just avoid doing so.

Comment: but I need to submit the form via code...

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the router to redirect to the new after the post completes.

```
export class ExampleComponent
  constructor(private router: Router) {}

  public function submitAndRedirect() {
    return this.http.post(GlobalVariables.SITE_ROOT + url, dto, { headers })
        .subscribe(function (data) {
          this.router.navigate(['newRoute', {id: id}]);
    });
  }
}
```